# Hexxit keeps crashing and won't let me on

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-technic-pack

On Technic Launcher, I can play on Tekkit and other servers, but when I click on Hexxit, it starts loading, then I get a black screen for a minute or so, then it just gives me a crash report. I used to be able to play on it just fine, worked perfect and never lagged or anything with my new computer, but one day it just wouldn't work and I haven't been able to since. I've tried redownloading it countless times, but it still hasn't done anything. Please help!
crash report:

```
Minecraft has crashed!      
----------------------      

Minecraft has stopped running because it encountered a problem; Failed to start game

A full error report has been saved to /Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/technic/modpacks/hexxit/crash-reports/crash-2014-08-24_19.08.02-client.txt - Please include a copy of that file (Not this screen!) if you report this crash to anyone; without it, they will not be able to help fix the crash :(



--- BEGIN ERROR REPORT aebc9846 --------
Full report at:
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/technic/modpacks/hexxit/crash-reports/crash-2014-08-24_19.08.02-client.txt
Please show that file to Mojang, NOT just this screen!

Generated 8/24/14 7:08 PM

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.5.2
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.9.3
    Java Version: 1.6.0_65, Apple Inc.
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Apple Inc.
    Memory: 74326584 bytes (70 MB) / 171872256 bytes (163 MB) up to 1065025536 bytes (1015 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: FML and Forge are installed
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v7.51 FML v5.2.23.737 Minecraft Forge 7.8.1.737 68 mods loaded, 68 mods active
    mcp{7.51} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    FML{5.2.23.737} [Forge Mod Loader] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Forge{7.8.1.737} [Minecraft Forge] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    CoFHFramework{1.5.2.5} [CoFH Framework] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    CodeChickenCore{0.8.7.3} [CodeChicken Core] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    NotEnoughItems{1.5.2.28} [Not Enough Items] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ImmibisMicroblocks{55.0.7} [Immibis's Microblocks] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    mod_bspkrsCore{v2.09(1.5.2)} [bspkrsCore] ([1.5.2]bspkrsCorev2.09.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    CoFHCore{1.5.2.5} [CoFHCore] (CoFHCore-1.5.2.5.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    CoFHWorld{1.5.2.5} [CoFHWorld] (CoFHCore-1.5.2.5.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    CustomLAN{2.2} [Custom LAN Mod] (CustomPortForge.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    TreeCapitator{Forge 1.5.2.r14} [TreeCapitator] ([1.5.2]TreeCapitator.Forge.1.5.2.r14.Uni.CoreMod.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ImmibisMicroblocksInstallCheck{55.0.7} [Immibis's Microblocks (Checks for incorrect installation, ignore this)] (immibis-microblocks-55.0.7.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    DamageIndicatorsMod{2.7.0.1} [Damage Indicators] (1.5.2 DamageIndicators v2.7.0.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    AsgardShield_Core{2.0.4} [AsgardShield] (1.5.2AsgardShield_Core_2.0.4Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ASAddon_Hallowed{2.0.0} [AS Addon- Hallowed] (1.5.2ASAddonHallowed_v2.0.0Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    HarkenScythe_Core{2.1.6} [HarkenScythe] (1.5.2HarkenScythe_v2.1.6Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ASAddon_HarkenScythe{2.0.0} [AS Addon- HarkenScythe] (1.5.2ASAddonHarkenScythe_v2.0.0Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ASAddon_NetherEnder{2.0.0} [AS Addon- Nether-Ender] (1.5.2ASAddonNetherEnder_v2.0.0Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ASAddon_ColorAPI{1.0.0} [ASAddon_ColorAPI] (1.5.2AsgardShield_Core_2.0.4Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    mod_ArmorBarMod{0.7.1} [Armor Bar Mod] (ArmorBarv0.7.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Artifice{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ArtificeCompat|Chisel{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Chisel] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ArtificeCompat|EE3{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: EE3] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ArtificeCompat|Forestry{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Forestry] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ArtificeCompat|MFR{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: MFR] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ArtificeCompat|Railcraft{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Railcraft] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ArtificeCompat|Vanilla{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Vanilla] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    mod_BackTools{1.5.2v1} [mod_BackTools] (BackTools1.5.2v1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BattleTowers{1.3.4} [Battle Towers] (BattleTowers_1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BetterDungeons{1.8} [Better dungeons] (BetterDungeons.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BiblioCraft{1.3.3} [BiblioCraft] (BiblioCraft[v1.3.3].zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    mod_BuffBarMod{0.7.1} [Buff Bar Mod] (BuffBarv0.7.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    DimDoors{1.5.2R1.4.1RC1} [Dimensional Doors] (DimensionalDoors-1.5.2R1.4.1RC1-194.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    eplus{1.15.4} [Enchanting Plus] (EnchantingPlus-1.15.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ExtrabiomesXL{3.13.4} [ExtrabiomesXL] (ExtrabiomesXL-universal-1.5.2-3.13.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    hexxitgear{1.5.2R1.0} [Hexxit Gear] (HexxitGear-1.0-23.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    InfernalMobs{1.3.1} [Infernal Mobs] (InfernalMobs_1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    inventorytweaks{1.54b} [Inventory Tweaks] (InventoryTweaks-1.54b.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Meteors{2.10.2} [Falling Meteors] (Meteors Mod V2.10.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    More Bows{1.5_v1} [More Bows mod] (More bows 1.5.2_2 Forge.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    NEIPlugins{1.0.9.3} [NEI Plugins] (NEIPlugins-1.0.9.3.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    LegendGear{1.5.2} [LegendGear] (NMcCoy-LegendGear-1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Natura{2.1.5} [Natura] (Natura_1.5.2_2.1.5.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Natura|CompatMineFactoryReloaded{0.1} [Natura compat: MFR] (Natura_1.5.2_2.1.5.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    OffLawn{1.0} [offLawn] (OffLawn-1.5.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ProjectZulu|Core{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Core] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Errored
    ProjectZulu|Blocks{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Block and Items] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Errored
    ProjectZulu|Dungeon{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Mobs] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Errored
    ProjectZulu|Mobs{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Mobs] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Errored
    ProjectZulu|World{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu World] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Errored
    xreliquary{1.5.2} [Xeno's Reliquary] (Reliquary1.0.6d.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    rftl{1.0} [RottenFleshToLeather] (RottenFleshToLeather-1.5.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    AS_Ruins{10.3} [Ruins Spawning System] (Ruins_1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    secretroomsmod{4.6.0} [SecretRoomsMod] (SecretRoomsMod-universal-4.6.0.283.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    SoulShards{1.0.16} [Soul Shards] (SoulShards-1.0.36-universal-srg.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    TConstruct{1.5.2_1.4.3d7} [Tinkers' Construct] (TConstruct_1.5.2_1.4.3.final.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    TConstruct|CompatMineFactoryReloaded{0.1} [TConstruct Compat: MFR] (TConstruct_1.5.2_1.4.3.final.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    WildCaves3{0.4.2} [Wild Caves 3] (WildCaves3-0.4.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BetterStorage{0.6.2.23-hotfix2} [BetterStorage] ([1.5.2]BetterStorage_0.6.2.23-hotfix2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Backpack{1.12.13} [Backpack] (backpack-1.12.13-1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ChestTransporter{1.1.6} [Chest Transporter] (chestTransporter_1.1.6_Universal.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ImmibisCore{55.1.6} [Immibis Core] (immibis-core-55.1.6.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MapWriter{2.0} [MapWriter] (mapwriter-2.0.5.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ObsidiPlates{1.5.0} [Obsidian Pressure Plates] (obsidiplates-1.5.2-universal-1.5.0.13.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    QuantumCraft{1.01} [qCraft] (qCraft1.01.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    TwilightForest{1.18.1} [The Twilight Forest] (twilightforest-1.18.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    chococraft{2.8.8} [Torojima's ChocoCraft] (zzzChococraft_2.8.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    LWJGL: 2.9.0
    OpenGL: Intel HD Graphics 5000 OpenGL Engine GL version 2.1 INTEL-8.26.34, Intel Inc.
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: Default
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown character '' in '/config/Project Zulu/ProjectZuluMobBiomeConfig.cfg:3150'
    at net.minecraftforge.common.Configuration.load(Configuration.java:625)
    at net.minecraftforge.common.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:100)
    at projectzulu.common.core.CustomEntityManager.loadCreaturesFromConfig(CustomEntityManager.java:25)
    at projectzulu.common.ProjectZulu_Core.load(ProjectZulu_Core.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:494)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:192)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:103)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:691)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:213)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:448)
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftAppletImpl.func_71384_a(SourceFile:56)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:733)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
--- END ERROR REPORT 2f75701e ----------
```

Comment: Tech support for modded minecraft is off-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't provide tech support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown character '' in '/config/Project Zulu/ProjectZuluMobBiomeConfig.cfg:3150'
```

It appears that there is an unknown character in the config file for the mod: project zulu, at line 3150.

This may be a bug on technic's side, but you should be able to remedy it by finding that unknown character in the config file and deleting or figuring out what it should be and changing it.

Your config files should be at `/Users/arlenemacarthur/Library/Application Support/technic/modpacks/hexxit/config`, since I see you are on a mac. You can get to that folder by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>, then copy paste the path into the box and press enter. This is your hexxit folder. You should be able to open the config file by right clicking on the file and selecting `open with: text edit`. Then check line 3150 for any weird characters and see if you can remove them safely.

Comment: to add, anyone who looks at the edit history in the original, badly formatted question, they will notice that where it says Unknown character it shows Unknown character '', however when i made everything formatted text (highlighted and pressed the pre-formatted text button), � was added

Comment: @Memor-X I've edited the question to restore the original *Unknown character ''* text.